# Can't read .bmp file containing a logical image in R

Tags: r, image, bmp

I have some .bmp image files created in Matlab from a logical matrix.  I can read these files in just fine using Matlab, and they open with every type of image viewing and processing software I have tried (ie. ImageViewer, GIMP, ImageJ), however when I try to read them using 'read.bmp' function from the 'bmp' library I get the following error:

```
Error in read.bmp('filename') : Do not know how to handle bit depth: 1
```

When I looked at the code for read.bmp, I saw it can only handle bit depths of 8, 24, and 32, I am assuming the bit depth of 1 in coming from the fact the image is logical.  If I rewrite the images in matlab as image*255, it reads just fine in R as well, but it is kind of a pain to have to rewrite all of these files in another language just to read them in R.

I also tried reading the images in with:

```
con=file('filename',open='rb')  
seek(con)
image=readBin(con,what='logical',size=1,n=imagewidth*imageheight,endian='little',signed=FALSE)
```

However the result was a vector 1/8 the size of the actual image.

I would greatly appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Comment: bitmap is despite its name a specific file format. you want to read a raster image. this should not be a problem.

Comment: Raffael, sorry I don't understand your comment.  I understand that a bitmap is a specific file format, however the 'BMP' package in R which handles this format doesn't handle the bit depth of this file, so as far as I can tell it is a problem.